# HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Internet Information Services (IIS)

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

My Company web server is running IIS 6.0 on windows server 2003 web edition.
when users go to our web site they get a password request then [this screen when cancel is hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMyCQ.png)

the logs all indicate 401.1, the IUSR built in account is used for the anonymous access with integrated windows authentication enabled.
in simple terms how can i get my web site to come back when users simply type the url in

help me obi wan kenobi your my only help

Comment: Windows Server 2003 went end of life years ago, so you can assume that knowledge has gone for ever. Upgrade to a supported Windows Server release (like 2019 or 2016) and that's the start.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://forums.asp.net/t/1459743.aspx?HTTP+Error+401+1+Unauthorized+Access+is+denied+due+to+invalid+credentials+